# function createInnerHTML - how to repeat with other form input?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below code;

.gs

```
function createInnerHTML() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("WELD DATE LOG");
  var namesValues = names.getRange(2,13,names.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
  var innerHTML = [];
  for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
    innerHTML.push({value:''+ namesValues[i][0], text:namesValues[i][0]});
  };
  return innerHTML;
}
```

.html

```
<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML(); ?>  
<select name="JOINT" id="JOINT" aria-label="JOINT" aria-required="true" required="">
<option value=""></option>
<? innerHTML.forEach(function(option) { ?>
  <option value="<?= option.value ?>"><?= option.text ?></option>
<? }); ?>
</select>
```

The purpose is to update the form options by a column in the spreadsheet where I have some related issues:

First, if the cell is blank, I need to remove the option from the form because it reads a blank option in the list

For example, when a user opens the options list in the form, it gives 4 options with two are blank and two with values instead of displaying the two values only

Second, how can I repeat the same function in the same script but with other form questions whether select or checkbox

For example, I have this html form with two input fields:

```
<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML(); ?>  
<select name="JOINT" id="JOINT" aria-label="JOINT" aria-required="true" required="">
<option value=""></option>
<? innerHTML.forEach(function(option) { ?>
<option value="<?= option.value ?>"><?= option.text ?></option>
<? }); ?>
</select>

<select name="WS" required>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="WS S01">WS S01</option>
<option value="WS S02">WS S02</option>
<option value="WS S03">WS S03</option>
<option value="WS S04">WS S04</option>
</select>
```

In the .gs file, I need to repeat the same mentioned function "function createInnerHTML()" with both form inputs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if the cell is blank` If the cell is blank can be corrected several ways.  You could use the  filter method on innerHTML or:

```
 function createInnerHTML() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("WELD DATE LOG");
  var namesValues = names.getRange(2,13,names.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
  var innerHTML = [];
  for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
    if(namesValues[i][0]) {
      innerHTML.push({value:''+ namesValues[i][0], text:namesValues[i][0]});
    }
  };
  return innerHTML;
}
```

`how can I repeat the same function in the same script but with other form questions whether select or checkbox`

You didn't supply any form information or spreadsheet data, so we don't really know the specifics to answer the question intelligently.  Please provide additional information and code requirements.

This is how I generally update a select:

gs:

```
function getSelectOptions() {
  sortOptions();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('gSSID'));
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}

function sortOptions() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('gSSID'));
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  rg.sort({column:1,ascending:true});
}
```

js:

```
function updateSelect(vA,id){
  var id=id || 'sel1';
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper for your interest. For removing empty cells from form options, I tried your modification but it gives a Syntax error in " if(namesValues[i][0] &&& nameValues[i][0]) { " then I removed one of the three & and it gave namesValues are not defined. Any ideas!

For repeating the script in the .gs file for other form inputs. I edited the question for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: I fixed the `&&&` and removed one of the `namesValues[i][0]`.  The rest of the code is just a copy of your code.  However, I must admit that's not how I would up a `select`.

Comment: Thank you Cooper. The if filter removes the blank values out of the choices. If I have another select question in the same form but with other values of course, how can I repeat the same function in the .gs file to update the second select question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the `if filter` and can you provide more specifics for the question your asking.  For example where would the options for the second select come from. Do you have a spreadsheet you can share.  I'm working in the dark here without a complete understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: In the below spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fuQK9VYk_rV9bO8DvL7iBHiupBtDmbqrv-GV-dirRTk/edit?usp=sharing

I need to update the first select options in the html file by Sheet2, column B

And also I need to update the second select options in the same html file but this time by Sheet3, column B

So how can I apply the same function "function createInnerHTML()" on different questions in the same html file form. Thanks

Comment: It's the same issue discussed here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112389/running-multiple-onedit-scripts?rq=1 but I'm not sure how to achieve that

Answer (score -1):

Okay I tried the below codes and they worked:

.html

```
<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML1(); ?>
<select name="List1" required="">
<option value=""></option>
<? innerHTML.forEach(function(option) { ?>
<option value="<?= option.value ?>"><?= option.text ?></option>
<? }); ?>
</select>

<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML2(); ?>  
<select name="List2" required="">
<option value=""></option>
<? innerHTML.forEach(function(option) { ?>
<option value="<?= option.value ?>"><?= option.text ?></option>
<? }); ?>
</select>
```

.gs

```
function createInnerHTML1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
var namesValues = names.getRange(2,14,names.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
var innerHTML = [];
for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
if(namesValues[i][0]) {
  innerHTML.push({value:''+ namesValues[i][0], text:namesValues[i][0]});
}
};
return innerHTML;
}


function createInnerHTML2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
var namesValues = names.getRange(2,11,names.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
var innerHTML = [];
for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
if(namesValues[i][0]) {
  innerHTML.push({value:''+ namesValues[i][0], text:namesValues[i][0]});
}
};
return innerHTML;
}
```

And so on you can repeat the same function in the .gs file with many inputs in the .html file. Thanks again Cooper